# Writing to hard disk more efficiently

Tags: c++, hard-drive

I'm writing streams of images to a hard disk using std::fstream. Since most hard disk drives have a 32MB cache, is it more efficient to create a buffer to accumulate image data up to 32MB and then write to disk, or is it as efficient to just write every image onto the disk?

Comment: i think you would let the cache work and don't necessarily try to 'help' it.

Comment: Do you actually have a problem with your write performance? If not, why bother?

Answer (score 2):

The cache is used as a read/write cache to alleviate problems due to queuing.... Here are my experiences with disks:

1. If the disk is not a SSD, then it's better if you write serially, than seek to files.. Seek is a killer for I/O performance.
2. The disks typically writes in sector sizes. sector sizes are usually 512b or 4k (newer disks). Try to write data one sector at a time.
3. Bunching I/O is always faster than multiple small I/Os. The simple reason is that the processor on the disk has a smaller queue to flush.
4. Whatever you can serve from memory, serve. Use disk only if necessary. You can always do an modify/invalidate cache entry on write, depending on your reliability policy. Make sure you don't swap, so your memory cache size must be reasonable, to begin with.
5. If you're doing this I/O management, make sure you don't double-buffer with your OS page cache. O_DIRECT for this.
6. Use non-blocking, if reliability isn't an issue. O_NONBLOCK

Answer (score 0):

Every part of your system, from `fstream` down to the disk driver knows more about specific efficiency than your application even has access to.

You couldn't improve upon the various buffering schemes if you tried, so don't bother.

Comment: That may or may not be true.  `fstream` is awfully generic, and it shouldn't be difficult to beat it for a specific use.  Depending on his use pattern and system, it is probably faster to either use `mmap` (or its Windows equivalent), or to do a single system level `write` of the data.  (Iostreams are largely text oriented, and IIUC, he's writing blocks of binary data.)

Comment: I don't disagree. Given that fstream is being used, it is indeed awfully generic, and between ostream buffering, filesystem buffering, disk operation ordering, disk-controller behavior, and disk hardware tricks, adding another layer of buffering isn't likely to help. The question is a tad lacking and of course one could do better, but given the information we've got, physical latency is likely dominant.